# Application to split file without making a copy?

Tags: windows

I've got a truly humongous file that I want to split (~500GB) and only 200GB of free space left. I obviously can't split it the conventional way, with 7zip or any other splitter utility I've been able to find, because that makes a copy as it goes, which would fill up my drive. Is there any program or nifty script out there that can split a file while erasing the original data at the same time? I do not have a HDD or any other really hefty external storage medium apart from some wimpy flash drives and DVD-RWs.

Comment: You might try dd. There is a windows port of it in the gnuwin32 core utils (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and an explanation of splitting and merging files here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/applications_gui_multimedia/splitting_and_merging_files_using_dd

Comment: Wow, thanks! That seems like it does basically exactly what I want, though it is a bit confusing